# Getting the element at the same level of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class to the preceding h3 element whenever any of the li under it being clicked, here is my html:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="marketing">
    <h3><a href="#" class="sales"> List I</a></h3>
        <div>
            <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
             </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="operations">
    <h3><a href="#" class="wise"> List II</a></h3>
        <div>
            <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">item a</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">item b</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">item c</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use the following script but in vain.

```
$('.list li').click(function () {
        $(this)parent().prev('h3').addClass('active');
    );
```

or either

```
$('.list li').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().children('h3')addClass('active');
    );
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$('.list li').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().prev().addClass('active');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/98/)

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
 $(this).closest('div').prev('h3').addClass('active');
```

or

```
 $(this).closest('div').siblings('h3').addClass('active');
```